# Reason to use Qt standard library function wrappers

Tags: qt, c-standard-library

Is there any reason to use Qt standard function wrappers like qstrncpy instead of strncpy?

I could not find any hint in documentation. And I'm curious if there is any functional difference. It looks like making code dependent on Qt, even in not mandatory places.

I found this: [Qt wrapper for C libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186031/qt-wrapper-for-c-libraries)
But it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Note that `strcpy` from C standard library `string.h` header is separate function from C++ `std::strcpy` from `cstring` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are part of Qt's efforts for platform-independence. Qt tries to hide platform differences and use the best each platform has to offer, replicating that functionality on platforms where it is not available. Here is what [the documentation of `qstrncpy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#qstrncpy) has to say:

> A safe strncpy() function.
>
> Copies at most len bytes from src (stopping at len or the terminating '\0' whichever comes first) into dst and returns a pointer to dst. **Guarantees that dst is '\0'-terminated.** If src or dst is nullptr, returns nullptr immediately.
>
> *[…]*
>
> Note: When compiling with Visual C++ compiler version 14.00 (Visual C++ 2005) or later, internally the function strncpy_s will be used.

So `qstrncpy` is safer than `strncpy`.

Comment: The `_s` suffix functions are not part of C++11. They are C11 and are not part of C++. Note that Microsoft had them in their library for a long time as non-standard Microsoft-specific functions.

Answer (score 1):

The Qt wrappers for these functions are safer than the standard ones because they guarantee the destination string will always be null-terminated. `strncpy()` does not guarantee this.

In C11, [strncpy_s()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)  and other `_s()` suffixed functions were added as safe string functions. However, they are not available in any C++ standard, they are C-only. The Qt wrappers fix this.